# get QML default value of a widget

Tags: application-development, qml

How to receive the default value of e.g. TextEdit `font.pointerSize`?

I would like to create a custom widget that uses some default values but allows to set some values from outside. Therefore it is necessary - as far as I know - to add a `property` variable that is accessible from outside (in this example it's `fontPointerSize`). I want this default property to be the default of an existing QML widget.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: background;
    color: "white";
    width: 200;
    height: 200;

    MyWidget {
        id: widget
        // fontPointerSize: 14
        anchors.topMargin: 8
        anchors.top: picker.bottom
    }
}
```

**MyWidget.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 26
    color: "orange"

    // how to get Text font.pointerSize default?
    property real fontPointerSize: 11

    Text {
        id: name
        text: qsTr("hello world")
        font.pointSize: fontPointerSize
        anchors.fill: parent

        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ignore my flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a [property alias](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-aliases).  In *MyWidget.qml*, use

```
property alias fontPointerSize: name.font.pointSize
```

Then, the `fontPointerSize` property will be the `font.pointSize` property of the `Text` element, and thus will start off with the default value.